# Can I concatenate certain fields of a table in a multitable SELECT in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with users, other table with user experiences and other with jobs (and much more). I want to SELECT all the users who applied for a job with a new field which is formed by the concatenation of all the experiences of the user, something like that:

```
SELECT users.*,jobs.id, jobs.name
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users.id = users_jobs.userId
LEFT JOIN jobs.id = users_jobs.jobId
LEFT JOIN users.id = user_experiences.userId
```

I need to add a field to the SELECT with all the experiences concatenated of each user. I am trying GROUP_CONCATENATE but it returns me only a row.

Any idea please?

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: GROUP BY "name_of_the_concatenated_field"?

Comment: No, the opposite, group by the other columns. The general GROUP BY rule is: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not completely sure I understood your question correctly, here is my attempt :

```
SELECT 
    users.*,
    jobs.id, 
    jobs.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(user_experiences.the_field_you_want_to_concatenate) AS concatenated_field
FROM users
LEFT JOIN users.id = users_jobs.userId
LEFT JOIN jobs.id = users_jobs.jobId
LEFT JOIN users.id = user_experiences.userId
GROUP BY 
     users.*,
     jobs.id,
     jobs.name;
```

Comment: Can I set a WHERE concatenated_fiel LIKE '%string%'?

Comment: I don't think you can in the same query. But you could do 2 things : either create a view with the query I wrote (my answer) and then make your WHERE on another query like this `SELECT foo FROM foo_view WHERE foo` or you can make the exact same thing that for the solution with the view but instead of foo_view you have the query with the group_concat. It would look like : `SELECT foo FROM (SELECT foo [...]) WHERE foo2;`